# Publish power bi dataset and create multiple reports in PBI service

Tags: service, powerbi, publish

I have a power Bi modelled dataset, I need to publish the dataset to power bi service. And then create separate reports on top of that modelled dataset. I would also like to know how to use the same dataset to create power bi report builder for some of the paginated reports. Will it be possible to edit/ transform/remodel the published dataset? In short, I need a single modelled dataset to be published into workspace(which can be editable later) and create multiple reports on top of that

As of now, I am creating a single report(pbix) file and publishing it which publishes both dataset and .pbix to the workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just import dataset from published report (NB! Dataset will NOT be available for edit in `powerquery`).
   [image]
2. If you need to edit dataset in `powerquery` after loading, use **`dataflows`** instead (NB! dataflows are NOT available in `My workspace`):

[image]

[image]